# Question about differential

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to do the following question:
Determine whether each of the following line integrals is independent of path. If it is, find a function $h$ such that $d h=P d x+Q d y$. If it is not, find a closed path $\gamma$ around which the integral is not zero. (a) $x d x+y d y$,  (c) $y d x+x d y$,

Solution
We compute the partial derivatve because if $h$ exist we have that $d h=$ $P d x+Q d y$ where $\partial P / \partial y=\partial Q / \partial x$.

(a)
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
P=x & Q=y \\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=0 & \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=0 \\
\int P d x=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+g(y) & \int Q d y=\frac{y^{2}}{2}+f(x) \\
\Rightarrow h=\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2} &
\end{array}
$$

$$
(c)
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
P=y & Q=x \\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=1 & \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=1 \\
\int^{P} P d x=x y+g(y) & \int Q d y=x y+f(x) \\
\Rightarrow h=x y &
\end{array}

For (a), it seems like that we get $h$ by adding the result from intergral of $Pdx$ and $Qdy$, but for part (c) why don't we add the both parts like in part (a) and get $2xy$?

Comment: $xy + xy$ isn't of the form $xy + g(y)$, since $xy$ contains an $x$ and so isn't purely a function of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not supposed to be a sum in any case.

If $dh = Pdx + Qdy$, then $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = P, \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} = Q$, and $h = \int Pdx = \int Q dy$.

In (a), we must have $\frac{x^2}{2} + g(y) = \frac{y^2}{2} + f(x)$, and let $g(y) = \frac{y^2}{2}, f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}$ would be fine.

In (c), we have $xy+g(y) = xy + f(x)$, and let $g(y)=f(x)=0$ would be great.

It is however, not an coincident that we have sum in the first case. Indeed $$P(x)dx + Q(y)dy=d(\int P(x) dx + \int Q(y)dy)$$ (that is when $P$ is a function of $x$ only and $Q$ is a funciton of $y$ only).